# Wealth of info? 69 Yamaha 100 L5T

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, motor-mounts, modification

Just picked up my dad's old 1969 yamaha 100 l5t that's been collecting dust for the past 35-40 years. Anyone know much about these bikes?

I'd like to get this thing running again and most likely swap something a little faster into the frame.

Anyone know what people have swapped into this frame or what the motor mounts share?

Thanks!

Comment: While I appreciate your enthusiasm, writing a question towards a specific issue you are having with the bike would be a great way to get started here at Mechanics.SE. Asking such a broad question is not such a good fit for the site.

Comment: Forums and clubs would be your best bet.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren - I would disagree. All he needs to do is ask questions suited to SE. Start fixing and when you have a problem, ask how to fix it.

Comment: Okay how do I fix a rusted out motor? If I need to find a new motor, will another motor fit this bike? @ErikvanDoren

Comment: @ahendren, I think you meant to address the comment to PAULSTER2. And if you used the comment to be more specific, then you should probably directly edit your question. (it might still be a bit too broad though, not sure)

Comment: @PAULSTER2, I never said don't ask in SE, I think there is a lot of knowledgeable and helpful people in here, But SE is "specific question - specific answer" and I don't think he is at that point yet. Forums allow discussions and he might have had already some suggestions with the question as it is now. In one shot he might find help, people willing to actually work with him and suggestions on where to find parts if needed. I think there's more probability in finding what he wants in MotorcycleForum or Yamahamotorcycleforum. Noone says not to ask here too if he has a specific problem.

Comment: Does this motor turn over?

Comment: @DucatiKiller ~ It used to but would not shift.

Comment: So that's a pretty nice little two-stroke motor in that bike.  Chances are you can make it run for little investment.  It pulls very good and is a great and desirable older trail bike.  If you can get it running I think you might be pretty happy with it.  So long as you don't expect it to pull you along like a super bike.  If you ask engine rebuilding questions related to it.  I will answer.  I think you would want to start with some questions about getting the ignition going (getting spark) and rebuilding the top end with the piston and what not.

Comment: I'm out for the weekend but as of Monday, I'll flow to those questions.  I've worked on two-strokes for a very long time and love two-stroke questions.  AND....the motor does turn over, right?

Comment: Thanks @DucatiKiller ! I actually found a complete rebuild of this engine and got it for a steal. I was gonna use the spare for parts or start piecing it out. I'm getting it next week. I need to get a new chain, tires/tubes, and I need to redo the lines. I'm trying to get the muffler off the old motor but need to get a tool to do so.

Comment: I also need to find spare nuts and bolts for random pieces like the seat and kick stand. I've been having trouble getting the kick stand back on the bike too. Looking forward to hearing back @DucatiKiller ! If you have any tips of how I should find these thing at a good price lmk